# Messing with joins, I want to get 2 tables data

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, firebird

**EDITED!!**

I'm struggling to get my data from  tables, but I have no luck.

#### My query

```sql
SELECT CODES.CODE, WARE.QTY
FROM   CODES 
LEFT JOIN WARE ON WARE.ID = CODES.ID
GROUP  BY CODES.CODE , WARE.QTY
ORDER BY CODES.CODE
```

My codes table is

```
CODE          |ID
--------------|-----------
1402201700006 | 123  
1102201700006 | 124
```

My ware table is

```
QTY           |ID
--------------|-----------
12            | 123
1             | 123
2             | 124
1             | 124
```

and my results are

```
CODE          |QTY
--------------|---------
123           |12
123           |1
124           |2
124           |1
```

instead of

```
CODE          |QTY
--------------|---------
123           |13
124           |3
```

Comment: Please show the DDL of the tables and describe their meaning in your deta model, add sample content of the tables involved, the expected result of the query and the actual result of the query. For example, I find it suspect that you are querying a table called `warehouse` to get the SKU of an item. I'd sooner expect that from a table called `item` or something. If `warehouse` stores the items in your warehouse, you might have multiple records per item (eg per warehouse, per physical item stored, per storage location, etc).

Comment: You have warehouses that attribute a different SKU to the same item (seems an unpractical thing). What do you want to happen in that case?

Comment: not having further information, i noticed, that in first query you use items.HEID = 'a78fa8a3' and in second items.id = 'a78fa8a3'. Also, you use items.itemid, when joining on basket... so how many ids do you have there in your items table? :) may be this makes a difference

Comment: @InnaTichman yes you are right, i edit my question and changed to .id , this happens because i want to provide a simple to understand query and not my real query

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes ! i have multiple records per item in that table. But its the only table i can find with the column i want to get in my query. :(

Comment: Just edited my original question to something more specific!

Answer (score 0):

I think that's beacause the "warehouse" table has multiple rows for every "id" in "items" table.

so you can use the query below:

```
SELECT items.name, color.color, size.size, SUM(basket.qty), warehouse.item_sku 
FROM items
INNER JOIN basket ON items.itemid = basket.itemid
INNER JOIN attributes color ON basket.attr1 = color.id
INNER JOIN attributes size ON basket.attr2 = size.id
INNER JOIN (select warehouse.itemid, max(warehouse.item_sku) item_sku from warehouse group by warehouse.itemid)warehouse ON items.id = warehouse.itemid
WHERE items.id = 'a78fa8a3'
GROUP BY items.name, color.color, size.size , warehouse.item_sku
```

Comment: Yes it has, this table may have each product multiple times !

Comment: I've edited the query to get max(item_sku) for each itemId